# How to make a DbSet property for a Model in DAL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-6.0, dbcontext

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to add a new Razor View with a Create template and a model that uses DatabaseContext as its class. The error I'm facing is as follows:

There was an error running the selected code generator:
'Could not add Model type 'IXP.Models.UserRegistrationModel' to DbContext 'DAL.DataContext.DatabaseContext'. Make sure that 'DAL.DataContext.DatabaseContext' has a DbSet property for 'IXP.Models.UserRegistrationModel'.'

In my .net 6 MVC solution, I have added two projects, "DAL" and "Domain." My code-first tables are located in the "Domain" project, while the DbSet properties for these tables are defined in the "DAL" project.

I hope this provides enough information to address this issue.

I attempted to add a DbSet in DAL.DataContext.DatabaseContext, but i couldnt.
"Domain" layer is correctly defined with the necessary attributes and properties as "Model"

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.